# R: Remove all variables stored in a list

Tags: r

How can I remove all variables from a specific environment, if the variable names are stored in a list?

I have for example:

```
a<-"1"
b<-"2"
MyList<-list(a,b)
rm(MyList)
```

MyList is removed, however not a and b which I want to be removed (as well).

Comment: but I don't want to mention a and b, since I want to keep it variable. I want to say remove MyList and all variablenames within MyList need to be removed

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you cannot.

When you create

```
 NewThing <- list(oldThing1, oldThing2)
```

The `NewThing` is it's own, new thing.  The only relation it has to `oldThing1 and 2` is the value.

---

Now if instead you had

```
NewThing <- list(oldThing1 = oldThing1, oldThing2 = oldThing2)
```

Then you could use

```
rm(list=names(NewThing))
```

But this, again, has nothing to do with the relationship between `NewThing` and `oldThing`.  Simply that the names of `NewThing` happen to be what you want to delete.

It would work just the same if you used

```
 NewThing <- list(oldThing1 = "Hello", oldThing2 = "There Dr Seuss")
 ..
 rm (list=names(NewThing))
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you can remove the varibles `a` and `b` from the global environment after you've created `MyList` by using `with` or `within`. This keeps `MyList` but removes `a` and `b`

```
> a <- "1"
> b <- "2"
> MyList <- list(a, b)
> with(MyList, rm(a, b, inherits = TRUE))
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
> b
Error: object 'b' not found
```

So `a` and `b` have been removed as variables in the global environment, but `MyList` remains.  To remove them all you'll have to do `rm(MyList, a, b)`

```
> MyList
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "2"
```